# Fragmented SQL Table on Disk

Tags: mysql, innodb, disk, query-performance

I have an instance of MySQL Server 5.6.20 running on Windows Server 2012.  One table in particular in my database is very large (23 GB on disk, 31 million rows).  When I query this table, even for simple operations such as a count(*), the performance is terrible, frequently taking as long as 40 minutes to complete.

Checking the resource monitor, I see my Highest Active Time pinned at 100%, but only reading 1.5-2.0 MB per second from the disk (much below the peak performance of the drive).  Internet research suggests this happens when reading highly fragmented files from disk, but the only file being read is the MySQL InnoDB database file.  Am I interpreting this right that the data file itself is heavily fragmented?  Is there an SQL specific solution or is windows defrag the correct approach to this problem?

[image]

**EDIT**

There are two Dell PERC H310 SCSI 1.8 TB Disks in the machine.  Only one is formatted.  RAID was never setup.  No SSDs are installed.

Comment: Are you using a RAID-type array? Is switching to SSD an option? Are you running your drives >90% full? I'm highly skeptical fragmentation is an issue. The operating system is usually pretty good about managing that and keeping it at an acceptable level.

Comment: @tadman - see edits.  Switching the SSD is always an option but I would much rather figure out whats wrong, both because I am curious and because it would be much less work than swapping the drive.

Comment: Bandwith used usually has nothing to do with input/output operations done. Mechanical disks have fairly low I/O capabilities and relatively large burst read capabilities - mostly used for false marketing as usual. That's the reason why SSD or RAID, like @tadman hinted, are the only sane choice when dealing with data-set that's I/O bound. As far as I know, the engine that won't fragment the data file(s) is TokuDB. I'm not sure whether InnoDB optimizes for such a case (I am 99.9% sure it doesn't), so it could be the case of fragmentation, hence low bandwith, hence a lot of I/Os spent.

Comment: @JHowIX Your drives could be thrashing like crazy, I have no idea based on your post. I repeat: Are you using RAID? Are your drives full?

Comment: @tadman - Yes I agree, there is much thrashing when reading this single data file, which is why I was wondering if there is some way to defrag the file from SQLs perspective - No RAID and the drive has 1.5 out of 1.8 TB free.

Comment: You could try defragmenting, but that's probably going to be a temporary performance boost at best. You'd be better off spending your time figuring out what queries are causing server load and finding ways of optimizing those, or by adjusting the tuning parameters on MySQL. For a performance-oriented database server, you want SSD, RAID10 for striping benefits, or both. Even RAID1 across your second drive could cut your seek times in half.